# springboot restcontroller redirect to Angular App URL

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a scenario where Springboot App receives a restful GET request [from IBM ISAM] with JWT token in the Header. Upon receiving this request, Springboot must redirect it to an Angular App and pass the JWT [either in Header or Query String].

I am trying out this in the Springboot but redirect doesn't happen in the browser.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/token")
public class RedirectController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public  ResponseEntity<Object> redirectToAngularApp(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headerItems) {

        System.out.println("Inside redirect....");

        System.out.println("Header Content::"+headerItems.toString());
        String jwttoken = ""; 



        if (headerItems != null) {

            String tokenString = headerItems.getValuesAsList("authorization").get(0);

            System.out.println("TOKEN STRING::"+tokenString);
            // && headerItems.startsWith("Bearer ")
            jwttoken = tokenString.substring(7);

            System.out.println("JWT TOKEN::"+jwttoken);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccessControlAllowOrigin("*");
        headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,OPTIONS,HEAD");
        headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
        headers.set("Access-Control-Max-Age","86400");
        headers.setLocation(URI.create("http://localhost:4200/#/dpsportal?token="+jwttoken));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);

    }

}
```

I get this error in the browser console.

```
Failed to load http://localhost:4200/#/: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
jwt.interceptor.ts:111 ERROR::{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
login.component.ts:68 TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (jwt.interceptor.ts:133)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onError (http.js:2302)
```

Please help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping("/foo")
  void handleFoo(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("some-url");
  }

}
```